# Regular polygons construction

Tags: geometry

Gauss had given a geometric method for  construction of a regular polygon of n=17 sides.

Was it the next easiest in the order of difficulty for construction after 5 sided polygon the  pentagon?  Why were polygons  n = 7,11,13 dropped out?

Comment: Have you read about the relationship (that Gauss found) between constructibility and Fermat primes? You can google Gauss-Wantzel.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon

Comment: No, can you please re-state it or give a link?